# How to get a function pointer to scipy.optimze minpack functions (hybrd)?

Tags: scipy, cython, numba

Quite a lot of scipy functions are wrapped using f2py. There is, to may knowledge, not really good documented way to extract a function pointer, but it is possible.

```
from scipy import interpolate
dir(interpolate.dfitpack.splev)
```

There is no `_cpointer` method shown, but it is there, see next example. Is there an alternative to `dir()` to really show all available methods/functions?

```
from ctypes import pythonapi
import ctypes

#https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/capsule.html

def capsule_name(capsule):
    pythonapi.PyCapsule_GetName.restype = ctypes.c_char_p
    pythonapi.PyCapsule_GetName.argtypes = [ctypes.py_object]
    return pythonapi.PyCapsule_GetName(capsule)

def get_f2py_function_address(capsule):
    name = capsule_name(capsule)
    pythonapi.PyCapsule_GetPointer.restype = ctypes.c_void_p
    pythonapi.PyCapsule_GetPointer.argtypes = [ctypes.py_object, ctypes.c_char_p]
    return pythonapi.PyCapsule_GetPointer(capsule, name)

#That is a function pointer which can be directly used in `Cython, Numba` or any package that can deal whith function pointers.
func_ptr=get_f2py_function_address(interpolate.dfitpack.splev._cpointer)
```

Because the first one working I'm also interested in procedures to extract a function pointer from functions not wrapped using `f2py`, or Cython functions with better [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/special.cython_special.html). A possible example would be :[`scipy.optimize._minpack import _hybrd`](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/main/scipy/optimize/__minpack.h)?

A simple `dir` gives no hint like in the previous example, but this was wrapped using `f2py`, while this package/function isn't.

Of course the functions are also not exported from the `dll/pyd` as in the first example.

Honestly, I expect an answer that it does not work without compiling everything independendly and so on....
But I also thought that for a long time for `f2py` wrapped functions, that's why I am asking this question. So a definite no, with some good explanation is also an answer.